# Changing a class with z-index

Tags: javascript, html

I'm still in the process of learning JavaScript. and I would like to complete the task using only JavaScript and no Jquery.

I have multiple div/images that I’m trying to manipulate using the z-index, and a button that randomize the images to come to the front.

I got the random image array to work but as you could see in image[1]…setting each changeZ index will be laborious. So I’m embarking on changing the class’s (as seen in image[0] so I could add current to the new image and send current to the background on the next go around and then removing the class attribute.  I have got the element to work separate but having trouble putting it together in a array.

```
function changeZIndex(i,id) { 
    document.getElementById(id).style.zIndex=i;}; 

function changeClassZIndex(i,tagName){
    document.getElementsByTagName("*").style.zIndex=i;};

function getImage(){ 

var whichImage=Math.floor(Math.random()*3); 

var image=new Array() 

var currentPhoto = div.current

image[0]=function() { 
    changeZIndex(5,"scene1"); 
    changeClassZIndex(-5,"current"); 
    currentPhoto.removeClass('current')
    document.getElementById("scene1").className += "current"; };


image[1]=function() { 
    changeZIndex(5,"scene2"); 
    changeZIndex(-5,"scene1");
    changeZIndex(-5,"scene3");
    changeZIndex(-5,"scene");  
}; 

image[2]=function() { 
    changeZIndex(5,"scene3"); 
    changeZIndex(-5,"scene");
    changeZIndex(-5,"scene2"); 
    changeZIndex(-5,"scene1");
}; 

image[whichImage].apply(undefined);};
```

Comment: Loops are handy tools for these kind of jobs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Statements#Loop_Statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because document.getElementsByTagName() returns an `array` of elements, which you can't do operations like that on. Instead, you need to enumerate through them and do the operations individually.

Here's a working jsfiddle which shows exactly how to do it: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YAeZu/20/)

---

As a side note: if there's one thing a lot of web programming will teach you, its this:

*Dont ever, **ever**, rule out jQuery as an option.*

JQuery is your best friend, and the use of it in this situation would cut down your lines of code by well over half.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I believe your problem is probably in changeClassZIndex(i,tagName)
which should probably look something like this:

```
if (document.getElementsByClassName == undefined) {
    document.getElementsByClassName = function(className)
    {
        var hasClassName = new RegExp("(?:^|\\s)" + className + "(?:$|\\s)");
        var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
        var results = [];

        var element;
        for (var i = 0; (element = allElements[i]) != null; i++) {
            var elementClass = element.className;
            if (elementClass && elementClass.indexOf(className) != -1 && hasClassName.test(elementClass))
                results.push(element);
        }

        return results;
    }
}

function changeClassZIndex(z,className) {
    var e = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
    for(var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
        e[i].style.zIndex = z;
    }
};
```

I am defining the getElementsByClassName function if it does not exist because some browsers may not support it.

I may suggest taking a different approach to your problem however:

```
var images = new Array("scene1", "scene2", "scene3");

var currentPhoto = div.current
var whichImage = Math.floor(Math.random()*images.length);

// change all images to the background
for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++)
{
    changeZIndex(-5, images[i]);
}
// change the one you want to the top
changeZIndex(5, images[whichImage]);
```

That way you do not have to write functions for each image, and adding images is as easy as adding to the array.

Comment: Your different approach works quite nicely   … not sure how it works but that is for me to figure out … Thank you.

Comment: I don't think I would overwrite the built-in getElementsByClassName function.. You run a risk of corrupting existing code, and now anyone who looks it this in the future is going to be confused. You're far better off leaving the logic to enumerate through the returned array in the "change" functions

Comment: It would not overwrite the built-in function, it only defines the function if it is undefined .. in that way any browser that provides the function will use it's method, and if not defined it will use this method. Granted this may be too complicated a solution for this answer, but it is required to be complete in all browsers.